# I deleted a package folder under node_modules by mistake

Tags: npm, node-modules

I deleted a folder under **node_modules** by mistake, should I run **npm install** in the project root to recover the deleted files without deleting the entire **node_modules** folder or should i delete the **node_modules** first and then run **npm i**?

If I run **npm install** without deleting the **node_modules** folder; will **npm install** only add the missing package files under the **node_modules**?

Answer (score 1):

You probably must be having `package.json` present in your project root directory. If you have so, then you can  then directly run `npm install` and all the packages and dependencies will be restored.